# Change value of same object in array in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4

I make some e commerce application for learning. Idea that user can put in cart same product several times, with different options.

i have some array, and i push into it object. I can push to this array same object several times. But when i push object, i`m need to chage one value of the object before that. This is code of
the service:

```
export class CartService {

  private cart = [];

  addProduct(product, qty){
    product['qty'] = qty;
    this.cart.push(product);
  }

}
```

i call function like that

```
this.cart.addProduct(this.product, this.count);
```

Problem is if i change value in inserting object, same value changed in same object in array. But i need change value just in inserting object.

For example, if in array already present object like that

```
{
  "productname": "Test",
  "qty": 1
}
```

And i push same object, but with another quantity. In first object in array, property qty chenges to.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are working with the same object reference, then if you edit one, the other (that it is the same object) also is edited. Maybe, you can create a clone of the original product and push it in the array.

```
 addProduct(product, qty){
    const newProduct = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(product));
    newProduct['qty'] = qty;
    this.cart.push(newProduct);
 }
```

I'm not sure if it is the best way to clone an object but I used it several times.